# submit returns to Home page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a simple PHP contact form on my website, the problem is that when I send a message the click on my submit button returns me to the Home page. I would like to avoid that and stay on the page.

Here's my code:

Header PHP:

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure that the phone field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['phone']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
}

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['weburl']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $weburl = trim($_POST['weburl']);
}

//Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!filter_var( trim($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'myemail@email.com'; // Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone Number: $phone \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
}
  ?>
```

Form:

```
  <div class="container">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Send Us a Message</legend>

        <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
          <p class="alert alert-danger">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information and try again. Thank you.</p>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p><strong>Message Successfully Sent!</strong></p>
            <p>Thank you for using our contact form, <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>! Your email was successfully sent and we&rsquo;ll be in touch with you soon.</p>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Your Name<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="form-control required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Your Phone Number<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Your Email<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control required email" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="weburl">Your Website<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="weburl" id="weburl" value="" class="form-control required url" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Subject<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control required" role="select" aria-required="true">
            <option></option>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message<span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <textarea rows="8" name="message" id="message" class="form-control required" role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
          <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
          <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remove all the data from the form." />
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div><!-- col -->
</div><!-- row -->

  <hr>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

JS:

```
   /* Bootstrap Contact Form
      ***************************************************************************/
 $(document).ready(function(){
// validate signup form on keyup and submit


var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    errorClass:'has-error',
    validClass:'has-success',
    errorElement:'div',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents(".has-error").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    },
    rules: {
        contactname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        weburl: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        contactname: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">Please enter your name.</span>',
            minlength: jQuery.format('<span class="help-block">Your name needs to be at least {0} characters.</span>')
        },
        email: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">Please enter a valid email address.</span>',
            minlength: '<span class="help-block">Please enter a valid email address.</span>'
        },
        weburl: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">You need to enter the address to your website.</span>',
            url: jQuery.format('<span class="help-block">You need to enter a valid URL.</span>')
        },
        phone: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">You need to enter your phone number.</span>',
            phoneUS: jQuery.format('<span class="help-block">You need to enter a valid phone number.</span>')
        },
        subject: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">You need to enter a subject.</span>'
        },
        message: {
            required: '<span class="help-block">You need to enter a message.</span>',
            minlength: jQuery.format('<span class="help-block">Enter at least {0} characters.</span>')
        }
    }
   });
  });
```

I think there might be a problem with

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
```

by using

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

I have tried to remove that, and also to use action="#" but without an effect, the submit button still redirects me to the landing page.

Comment: is there any URL rewrite of any sort? What's the URL of the page containing the form?

Comment: @Salketer there's only one main URL for the whole web, the contact form is placed in a Slide out Panel without an URL

Comment: There must be some URL Rewriting going on, there does not seem to be any code that you showed us that is doing it.

Comment: The form has been jiggled by BootStrap, there is actually no `action=`  on it at all. Take a look at the pagesource. Look to your bootstrap/javascript code

Comment: @RiggsFolly my fault, I updated different versions of it to my domain, going to try it with action, but while I am trying everything on localhost nothing works

Answer (score 1):

You mention "there's only one main URL for the whole web, the contact form is placed in a Slide out Panel without an URL".  I'm not sure how you're generating your slide out panel, but I'm guessing it is just revealing/animating some hidden content already on that page - maybe a Bootstrap modal.

So you have a single page, maybe index.php, with a contact form on it.  Your form action (where data is POSTed to) is `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`, which will be "index.php" (check, view source or look in dev tools).

So hitting submit, assuming the JS validation passes, will POST the form data to index.php.  The POST is a new request, so on the front end the page will appear to reload, though this time there is a POST payload that your header PHP will process.  Your contact form will disappear, since it is not normally displayed on the page until triggered by a click on a link or button or whatever.

It sounds like you actually want the page to not refresh, and the contact form display to be updated with your success or error msgs ("Message Successfully Sent!", etc).  To do that, you need to POST via AJAX, which will happen in the background without refreshing the page.

To do that, you need to first update your PHP to return a response that your Javascript can use, and not generate the whole page like it does on a GET request.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // ... all your existing code ...

    if ($hasError) {
        echo "FAIL";
    } else {
        echo "OK";
    }

    die();  // POSTs to this page only generate success/error msgs, and bail out
}
```

Next you need to add a submit handler to your validation:

```
var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    ...
    messages: {
    ...
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === 'OK') {
                    // JS code to reveal your success alert, eg:
                    // $('div.alert-success').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    // JS code to reveal your danger alert
                }
            }
        });
        return false; // Block the normal submit, we just did it via AJAX
    }
```

Lastly, remove the PHP conditions for displaying the success/danger alerts, as you are now going to show them via Javascript.  Just add a "hidden" class to them so that on first load neither are displayed.

You could make things a bit neater by having just one alert area, with the content and class generated by the PHP, eg instead of just returning "OK" it could return JSON (make sure to add dataType: 'json' to your $.ajax() call in that case).

Answer (score 0):

You must defined your page in this attribute :

```
action="your_page.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

it`s path to root dir like /

form has a own ability to reload page when submitted, thats why its redirects you to homepage

you should use AJAX to stay on this page when form submitted

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you are using a one pager without tracking where the user was when clicking on the contact form, your easiest bet is to use the `target` attribute to send the form submit in an hidden iframe. Then you use the javascript to just hide the contact form.

This will have the benefit to not reload the page while still sending the form. Also you could write JavaScript in the form submission page using `top` to send information to your main page, and display a little message like "thank you for your feedback" when the form is correctly submitted.

Comment: I am going to try this for sure. Thanks for explaining it a bit more

Comment: I suggest you look into location hash. It can be used to remember where a user is, and using some scripting at page load you could easily find that hash and send the user to the right view... That would make it a 2 step integration, first you'd need to track each view change and put the corresponding hash in the document location, and then act accordingly on page load. Using this would also let the user navigate using their back/forward browser buttons